# Javafx image is not found

Tags: java, javafx

i have this code in my JavaFX code

```
Image arrowRight = new Image("/Users/murad/Desktop/arrowright.png");
ImageView arrowRightv = new ImageView(arrowRight);
```

My goal is to find the image that is on my desktop and then to put it on the screen.But this code returns me this error:

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62
)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl
.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherIm
pl.java:389)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:
328)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62
)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl
.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:767)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java
:917)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$155(Launche
rImpl.java:182)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid URL: unknown protocol: c
    at javafx.scene.image.Image.validateUrl(Image.java:1121)
    at javafx.scene.image.Image.<init>(Image.java:620)
    at Kanban.start(Kanban.java:152)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$162(Launch
erImpl.java:863)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$175(PlatformImpl.j
ava:326)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$173(PlatformImpl.java:29
5)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$174(PlatformImpl.jav
a:294)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java
:95)
Caused by: java.net.MalformedURLException: unknown protocol: c
    at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:600)
    at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:490)
    at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:439)
    at javafx.scene.image.Image.validateUrl(Image.java:1115)
    ... 8 more
```

I tried doing what i did above with `FileInputStream`,but that didn't work.Also i got the url from Mac,so it's definitely not wrong.
What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parameter is an URL,

```
"file:/Users/murad/Desktop/arrowright.png"
```

The error show that you were on Windows with "c:/...." - hence the error that no protocol `c` exists. ("file:///c:/...").